# 'Column 'CustID' does not allow nulls.' error when trying to write to access database VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, error-handling, null

I'm trying to write to my database from textboxes in VB form. But when I click the 'add'button, this error is given under the `CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit() line even though all my textboxes are filled in.

```
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString)

        connection.Open()

        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into Items([InvoiceID]. [Item],[Cost],[Quantity]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("CustID", CType(CustIDTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("FirstName", CType(First_NameTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("LastName", CType(Last_NameTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Address", CType(AddressTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("PhoneNo", CType(Phone_noTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Points", CType(PointsTextBox.Text, String)))

        CustomersBindingSource.AddNew()
        CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        CustomersTableAdapter.Update(POS_database_latestDataSet.Customers)

 End Using
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your Insert statement doesn't seem to have anything to do with your parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Since the sql string and the parameters didn't match I picked the parameters and changed the sql string. I had to guess the table name and field names in the database. Please check for the correct names. If a field is an auto-number field (usually found as the primary key, and ID field) you do not insert a value for that field. The database will insert the value for you.

Both connections and commands need to be disposed, so include the command in the `Using` block by putting a comma after the first line and removing the `Dim`.

Don't open the connection until just before the command is executed.

The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is a `String`. You do not need the convert the type.

I used a `With...End With` to save a little clutter.

In `OleDb` the order that the parameters appear in the sql string must match the order they are added to the parameters collection. The `Add` method will create a new `Parameter` object and add it to the parameters collection. I had to guess at the datatypes. Check your database.

You wrote all that lovely command code and then you completely ignored it. Executing the command will update the database.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim str = "Insert into Customers(FirsName, LastName, Address, PhoneNo, Points) Values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @PhoneNo, @Points);"
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString),
            cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, connection)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = First_NameTextBox.Text
            .Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Last_NameTextBox.Text
            .Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = AddressTextBox.Text
            .Add("@PhoneNo", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Phone_noTextBox.Text
            .Add("@Points", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(PointsTextBox.Text)
        End With
        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I did as you suggested, but now when I run the program and click 'add', I get the error : 'Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.' Even though the values stated are the same as the database fields

Comment: Hey so I managed to figure that out. But now there's something new: : 'The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'FirstName'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.' I've double checked, the names all match.

Comment: @HamzaAsim In the Access database check the names of the fields (columns). Make sure there is a field named FirstName. No spaces, or other characters that don't show.

Answer (score 2):

Just as the error states, that column does not allow `NULL` values.  And you're not inserting a value into it.  You're inserting into these columns:

```
([InvoiceID]. [Item],[Cost],[Quantity])
```

Which (1) looks like a typo between the first two columns and (2) doesn't even resemble the *values* you're trying to insert.

Specify the columns that you want to insert the values into:

```
([CustID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Address], [PhoneNo], [Points])
```